# Setting value to input field using jquery is not setting to the model of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<input type=text ng-model="name" id="nameId"/>
```

Now if I set

```
$('#nameId').val('angular');
```

This is setting the value in view by showing on screen.

But this value is not set to the model.
That is $scope.name is empty
I am expecting `$scope.name` also to be "angular"

Comment: You should avoid externally manipulating things that are placed in the control of the AngularJS framework. You could possibly force it to update the model by triggering the `change` event on the element after setting the value, but really, if you want to programmatically set the value you should set it on `$scope.name`, that's the entire purpose of AngularJS' two-way data binding.

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: The AngularJS [`<input>` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) and the [ngModel Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) override the default event handlers and set the`value` property of the [`<input>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). What are you trying to do by modifying this property externally with jQuery? Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

As you change that value outside of Angular world `$scope.$apply` you need to tell angular to re-evaluate the bindings. So inside of your controller,

```
$scope.$apply(() => {
  $('#nameId').val('angular');
});
```

Comment: Yes, but why? If you can keep everything inside Angular ecosystem why to do it with JQuery?